# Setting my country and locale in Facebook

Tags: facebook, locale, country, country-codes

I have an FB app that uses country and locale codes to display alternative content to users.

Does anyone know how I can change my user account's locale and country in Facebook so I can test the different values that are returned by the system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can also force the Facebook to open a page or application in a specific language with calling the URL with some additional parameters like this:
https://apps.facebook.com/your-app-name/?locale=en_US  (english)
https://apps.facebook.com/your-app-name/?locale=hu_HU  (hungarian)

Answer (score 1):

Arrow near Home > Account settings > General > Language